# Avatar not moving smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With the left and right arrow key's i should be able to move an avatar to the left and right. 
It's, however, not running smoothly because it move's like: go-stop-go-stop when you hold the arrow key.

see fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zk45xgnd/2/

html:

```
<div id='avtr'></div>
```

css:

```
#avtr {
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:#f00;
}
```

jquery:

```
var allowedToWalk = false, allowedToWalkTime = true;
var percentage = 1;
var maxWidth = 1000;
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {

        if(e.which == 39) {
            //move to right
            allowedToWalk = true;
            avatarMoveRight();

        }
        if(e.which == 37) {
            //move to left
            allowedToWalk = true;
            avatarMoveLeft();

        }
    }).keyup(function() {
        allowedToWalk = false;
    });

    function avatarMoveRight() {
        if(allowedToWalk != false && allowedToWalkTime != false) {
            var pos = $("#avtr").css('left');
            pos = pos.replace('px', '');
            pos = pos - 0;
            if((pos - 40) < (percentage * maxWidth)) {
                allowedToWalkTime = false;
                $("#avtr").animate({left: '+=40'}, 150);
                setTimeout(function() {allowedToWalkTime = true;},150);
            }

        }
    }

    function avatarMoveLeft() {
        if(allowedToWalk != false && allowedToWalkTime != false) {
            var pos = $("#avtr").css('left');
            pos = pos.replace('px', '');
            pos = pos - 0;
            if((pos - 4) > 0) {
                allowedToWalkTime = false;
                $("#avtr").animate({left: '-=40'}, 150);
                setTimeout(function() {allowedToWalkTime = true;},150);
            }


        }
    }
```

How to make it smooth running when holding the arrow key?

SOLUTION by @adam A
https://jsfiddle.net/zk45xgnd/3/

Comment: You're jumping 40 pixels at a time, you could try lowering that to a smaller number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated code with lower values and wait time between movements, this gives it a slightly more fluid animation. However, I'd suggest looking into GSAP animation library of Phaser for some really advanced stuff.

```
var allowedToWalk = false, allowedToWalkTime = true;
var percentage = 1;
var maxWidth = 1000;
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {

        if(e.which == 39) {
            //move to right
            allowedToWalk = true;
            avatarMoveRight();

        }
        if(e.which == 37) {
            //move to left
            allowedToWalk = true;
            avatarMoveLeft();

        }
    }).keyup(function() {
        allowedToWalk = false;
    });

    function avatarMoveRight() {
        if(allowedToWalk != false && allowedToWalkTime != false) {
            var pos = $("#avtr").css('left');
            pos = pos.replace('px', '');
            pos = pos - 0;
            if((pos - 40) < (percentage * maxWidth)) {
                allowedToWalkTime = false;
                $("#avtr").animate({left: '+=5'}, 5);
                setTimeout(function() {allowedToWalkTime = true;},5);
            }

        }
    }

    function avatarMoveLeft() {
        if(allowedToWalk != false && allowedToWalkTime != false) {
            var pos = $("#avtr").css('left');
            pos = pos.replace('px', '');
            pos = pos - 0;
            if((pos - 4) > 0) {
                allowedToWalkTime = false;
                $("#avtr").animate({left: '-=5'}, 5);
                setTimeout(function() {allowedToWalkTime = true;},5);
            }


        }
    }
```